# Bash if kill hangs then kill -9

Tags: bash, kill

I am trying to write a bash function that tries to `kill` pids. If the `kill` hangs for `x` time then `kill -9` pids;

```
kill_service() {
    service="$1"
    pids="$(ps -s "$(ps -ef | awk '/runsv\ '"${service}"'$/ { print $2 }')" -o pid=)"
    if ! kill $pids; then
    kill -0 $pids
    fi
}
```

I may be trying to reinvent the wheel, but I basically want to try to kill, then after x time if it's not killed gracefully, then kill with fire!

I know I could use a while loop or something like this as the service sues symlinks if its up;

```
kill_service() {
    service="$1"
    time_to_wait="${2:-300}" # If no time_to_wait given, 300 seconds used as default
    pids="$(ps -s "$(ps -ef | awk '/runsv\ '"${service}"'$/ { print $2 }')" -o pid= | tr -d '\n'| sed 's/ //')"
    kill $pids
    retries=10
while ((retries > 0)); do
    # still alive?
    [[ -L /service/${service}/ ]] || exit;
    sleep $time_to_wait;
    ((retries --))
done

# 10 iteration loop and still alive? be brutal
kill -9 $pids
}
```

but wondered if there's a cleaner way?

Comment: In your code, I don't understand the `-o` option for `ps` (my _ps_ does not have `-o`),and your _still alive_ checking, in particular since the variable `pids_directory` is never initialized.

Comment: I would put all the PIDs into an **associative array**, then loop over them and do the `kill`. If after killing the process is not here anymore, remove the item from the array.  If the array becomes empty, you know that you have killed all of them. Since you have an associative array, the value of the array elements could be the number of retries for this element, so you can monitor the retries for each PID separtely if you want.

Comment: @user1934428 The interface to `ps` (or rather, the various versions of `ps`) is kind of a mess. It would probably be cleaner to use `pkill` if available to avoid having to find process ids manually.

Comment: If you need to use `kill -9`, something is *very* wrong with your service, and you should fix that rather than trying to automate the use of `kill -9`.

Comment: [gnu `kill`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) has a timeout option which, if used multiple times with escalating signals for a single call, appears to do exactly what you want. You will likely need do something to avoid the bash built-in, e.g. say `/bin/kill` or precede it with `enable -n kill`.

Comment: Also notable: Calling `kill` multiple times with the same PID is not bug-proof because of a race condition: If the originl process *did* terminate the same PID may have been assigned to a different process which the second `kill` inadvertently kills.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica : I was thinking about this too, but at least as long as you are not on Windows, AFIK the PIDs are used in a round-robin fashion, and unless we are talking about retries which stretch over a period of many hours, this should be a mere theoretical possibility. If you go to that extent, you would also have to consider the case that between collecting the set of PIDs, and doing the first kill, the original process might have terminated by its own and another started with the same pid.

Comment: @user1934428 True!

Comment: For reasons not worth going into, I am running a very old version of kill so no --timeout option. I need to use kill then kill -9, again for reasons beyond the scope of the question. the -o pid= removes the header